# What are some examples of small-scale physical phenomena that snakes fear?

Tags: zoology, ethology, snake

What are some ways to use technology to repel snakes?

One idea I was researching is low-frequency sound, which I read snakes could "feel" even though they are naturally deaf. Would this be a viable option? What sound ranges would need to be used?

What are some other ways? Could targeted light be another option?